# Qual è il senso di "riacciuffato a fatica sull’orlo" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Diceria dell'untore*, di Gesualdo Bufalino, ho letto:

> Mi chiedo tuttora cosa cercasse nella mia compagnia,
>   se gli servisse solo un ascoltatore acquiescente per le sue
>   empiaggini d’ogni sera, oppure obbedisse alla professionale curiosità di censire da vicino i progressi del male
>   dentro di me, le crepe neonate, i capisaldi persi, ripresi,
>   ripersi; e tutto questo non su una di quelle gocciolanti
>   pellicole che detestava, bensì attraverso più sottili spionaggi: una veemenza nella tosse che prima non c’era;
>   una nota che la voce avesse improvvisamente fallito o
>   **riacciuffato a fatica sull’orlo**; un’unghia spaccata, una
>   roseola sul labbro, un lampo di febbre nell’iride.

L'io narrante è un malato di tubercolosi (il proprio Bufalino da giovane, infatti), mentre il brano fa riferimento a un medico.

Il significato di "empiaggini" l'ho trovato su [questo sito web](http://www.retididedalus.it/Archivi/2010/giugno/LUOGO_COMUNE/1_bufalino.htm). Comunque, malgrado abbia cercato i vocaboli "riacciuffare" e "orlo" in alcuni dizionari, non riesco a capire il senso dell'espressione "riacciuffato a fatica sull’orlo" in questo passaggio. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si riferisce alle note che la voce avrebbe *ripreso al limite* (o *riacchiappato al pelo*, per usare una forma più colloquiale). In sostanza il medico cercava degli elementi che denotassero dei miglioramenti o dei peggioramenti nel decorso della malattia, comprese delle incertezze nell'eloquio: una nota fallita, poiché magari interrotta da un colpo di tosse o altro inghippo, oppure una nota non proprio fallita, in procinto di fallire ma ripresa proprio all'ultimo momento dal malato che parla.
Un po' come se fosse una cosa che ti sta scappando, sfuggendo, e riesci a riprenderla giusto in tempo.